# Converting a string to datetime format with a non standard value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have an issue, a column I created contains an nvarchar field with dates that are in this format '2016:10:12 13:27:05'

```
convert(DATETIME, DATE_TAKEN)
```

returns this

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

They are in this format because they are taken from the meta data from photos, is there anyway I can convert it to datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(DATE_TAKEN, t.i), ':', '-') + 
            RIGHT(DATE_TAKEN, t.l - t.i) AS DATETIME)
FROM mytable
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', DATE_TAKEN), 
          LEN(DATE_TAKEN)) AS t(i, l)
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/WTCMD45491)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stuff()` and to fix the initial colons.  Then, I would explicitly use the format as well:

```
select convert(DATETIME, stuff(stuff(DATE_TAKEN, 5, 1, '-'), 8, 1, '-'), 120)
```

Comment: @k_schultz try it now

Comment: What if there is a date like '2016:1:12 13:27:05'?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date varchar(50) = '2016:10:12 13:27:05';

declare @spaceIndex int = charindex(' ', @date);
declare @dateVal varchar(10) = replace(left(@date, @spaceIndex),':','.')
declare @timeVal varchar(10) = right(@date, len(@date) - @spaceIndex)

--using the variables
select convert(Datetime, @dateVal +' '+ @timeVal)
--or inline version
select convert(Datetime, replace(left(@date, charindex(' ', @date)),':','.') +' '+ right(@date, len(@date) - charindex(' ', @date)))
```